# Second masters degree or PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, funding, computer-science

So this year I'm finishing my masters degree in Security of Information Systems, in a third world country University (best in my country but still) , and I might have a chance at a fully funded scholarship in a way better university abroad, I was thinking of getting a second masters degree in robotics, Artificial intelligence or Cognitive systems.

Is it worth it ? with a bachelor degree in Computer science and a masters in SIS do I fulfil the requirements ?

There is also the matter that I'm going to be fully relying on the scholarship's funding, and of course I still can try to apply for a Ph.D scholarship abroad, but I heard it's more difficult to get it.

Getting a PhD in my country would be fairly easy, but that's not something I'm really interested in for several reasons, First the pace and level of research over here is not really that good. Second, I'm thinking an experience abroad might really help me at many levels. And here comes the point I'm not really sure about, does having 2 masters degrees give me a chance at a better job ? or a better chance at getting accepted for a PhD ?

PS : The graduation project I'm working on right now is a mix of Forensics, Security, massive parallel computing and artificial intelligence.

Thank you

**EDIT :** 
Okay, I am to rephrase my question, I'm a passionate learner, I want to have the experience of studying abroad, I enjoy many fields in computer science, my question is, can this actually hurt my career ? personally I don't mind "postponing" its start, as long as it's harmless and I'm doing something I enjoy.

Comment: [Search the site](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=second+master+degree) and you will find many similar questions to your own.

Comment: Thanks, I did a check them out, and i thought maybe i could get something more specific for my situation.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a meaningful answer to this question. You ask "is it worth it?" but that depends so much on what is important to you. You ask does a second masters give you a chance at a better job but what kind of a job? If you add all the details, I'm concerned that the question will be closed as being too specific to you (and not helpful to others). Perhaps you could find a way to re-word the question to be more answerable without being too narrow?

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not get the phd abroad after taking the second master's?

Comment: That is kinda my Ultimate goal, but I've been told getting accepted for a PhD abroad isn't that easy, especially getting an extended scholarship. Maybe if I get a part time job/summer job there while getting my masters and save enough to afford staying without the need of a scholarship, that would be worth it.

Comment: To my opinion you better get PhD rather than second master. It will put you on a different position and it will be easy to find job.

Comment: Given your edit, your new question ("can this actually hurt my career") seems to be an exact duplicate of one that's already asked on this site.